# Find entries with identical magnitude and sort them by the imaginary part in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `x` with complex entries and I want to do the following:

Let's say there are entries with the same absolute value, for example `13`, `5+12i` and `5-12i`. If I put those in the builtin `sort` function, it will put `13` at first, then `5-12i` and then `5+12i`. However, since all of those have the same magnitude, I want to sort them by their imaginary part, so I would like to have `5-12i` come first, then `13` and then `5+12i`. What is the easiest way of doing this, without using any loops or if statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct a matrix that has the magnitude as the first column and the imaginary component as the second column and then use [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) to sort the result which will sort first by the first column (the magnitude) and then by the second column (the imaginary component). You can use [the second output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html#outputarg_index) of `sortrows` to get the corresponding indices of the sorted rows which you can then use to sort the original data.

```
data = [13, 5+12i, 5-12i];

[~, inds] = sortrows([abs(data(:)), imag(data(:))]);
sorted = data(inds);
%   5.0000 - 12.000i    13.0000 + 0.0000i   5.0000 +12.0000i
```